# Возврат из fragment в activity

Tags: android-fragment, backbutton

При нажатии на одну из кнопок в activity, поверх нее появляется fragment. Вопрос: как вернуться обратно в activity при помощи кнопки Back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переопределите метод `onBackPressed`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
       mFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
    else super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Чтобы это сработало надо ещё добавить фрагмент в стек

```
FragmentManager mFragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("Тег добавляемого фрагмента");
fragmentTransaction.add("container id", fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```